# How to sign oauth signature for request token with etrade api?

Tags: node.js, oauth, crypt, etrade-api

I'm trying to hook into eTrade's API for a project. They use an OAuth v1 flow. I'm running into error's on the very first step of the flow- getting the request token. The info from their doc's can be found [here](https://apisb.etrade.com/docs/api/authorization/request_token.html).

The error I'm getting is 401- invalid signature.

I've been reading up on the OAuth flow [here](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step1) and have become familiar with the process. In the past I've used PassportJS for 3rd party integrations.

So eTrade has provided me 4 keys- PROD_KEY, PROD_SECRET, SANDBOX_KEY, SANDBOX_SECRET. I'm using the sandbox keys for now as my production key is still pending.

Now I have an endpoint on my API that I'll call from my client to get the request tokens. It's structure like this:

```
router.route('/auth/request').get(controller.request);
```

And the following controller is where I'm generating a signature and trying to request the token from eTrade. That controller looks like this:

```
// controllers/auth.js

const axios = require('axios');
const { v1 } = require('uuid');
const crypto = require('crypto');

function generateSignature() {
  const method = 'GET',
        url = 'http://localhost/',
        encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(url),
        paramaters = {
          oauth_consumer_key: process.env.ETRADE_SANDBOX_API_KEY,
          oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
          oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
          oauth_nonce: v1(),
          oauth_callback: 'oob'
        }

  var ordered = {};
  Object.keys(paramaters).sort().forEach((key) => {
    ordered[key] = paramaters[key];
  });

  var encodedParameters = '';

  for(k in ordered) {
    const encodedValue = escape(ordered[k]);
    const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(k);

    if(encodedParameters === '') {
      encodedParameters += encodeURIComponent(`${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`);
    } else {
      encodedParameters += encodeURIComponent(`&${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`);
    }
  }

  encodedParameters = encodeURIComponent(encodedParameters);

  const signature_base_string = `${method}&${encodedUrl}&${encodedParameters}`;
  const signing_key = `${process.env.ETRADE_SANDBOX_SECRET_KEY}`;
  const signature = crypto.createHmac("SHA1", signing_key).update(signature_base_string).digest().toString('base64');
  const encodedSignature = encodeURIComponent(signature);

  return encodedSignature;
}

module.exports = {
  request: async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Fetching request token from etrade...');

    try {
      var response = await axios.get(`https://api.etrade.com/oauth/request_token`, {
        params: {
          oauth_consumer_key: process.env.ETRADE_SANDBOX_API_KEY,
          oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
          oauth_signature: generateSignature(),
          oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
          oauth_nonce: v1(),
          oauth_callback: 'oob'
        }
      });

      console.log('Fetched request token...', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Could not fetch request token...', error.response.data);
    }
  }
}
```

I have followed some guides on the internet to help me understand the process of signing a request, but I can't seem to get a valid response back.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is targeting the etrade production URL. Try calling the sandbox URL.

```
Production  https://api.etrade.com/v1/{module}/{endpoint}
Sandbox     https://apisb.etrade.com/v1/{module}/{endpoint}
```

Comment: they dont define a sandbox url for the request_token endpoint like they do with the other endpoints. I tried apisb.etrade.com/oauth/request_token and got same error. I will try again though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer on this, but I think the following might help. I ran into a similar issue while I was trying to integrate with their API (I am using java though). Looking into their sample code, I realized that the keys to sign the baseString requires an extra '&' at the end for request_token API. See the following code from their sample application  -

```java
       if( token != null){
            // not applicable for request_token API call
             key = StringUtils.isEmpty(token.getOauth_token_secret()) ? context.getResouces().getSharedSecret() +"&" : 
                 context.getResouces().getSharedSecret()+"&" + OAuth1Template.encode(token.getOauth_token_secret());
        }else{
            // applicable for request_token API call
            key =  context.getResouces().getSharedSecret() +"&";
        }
```

AFAIK, this is not oAuth standard or anything. This seems to be very specific to their implementation. Anyways, I updated my code to include the extra '&' at the end & it started working.

```java
  private String signBaseString(String httpMethod, String url) {
    StringBuilder baseString = new StringBuilder();
    baseString.append(encode(httpMethod)).append("&").append(encode(url)).append("&");
    baseString.append(encode(normalizeParams(url)));
    // the extra & is added here.
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec((this.apiSecret + "&").getBytes(), SIGN_ALG);
    Mac mac = null;
    try {
      mac = Mac.getInstance(SIGN_ALG);
      mac.init(signingKey);
      return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(
          mac.doFinal(baseString.toString().getBytes(
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
      logger.error("Error during signing headers", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely let you know

Comment: I am finding the etrade api documentation to be lacking and I think the problem is with signing the request token correctly. Thanks for posting about the '&' issue. I added that, but I'm still not able to connect - Is is necessary to add the callback and version info when generating the signature?